# `Latin Modern Roman` as main font in xelatex project

Tags: xetex, latin-modern

I want to use Latin Modern font in my xelatex project. While compiling, xelatex reports:

> ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Latin Modern Roman" cannot be
>   found.

The font comes with TeX Live 2019, which I am using. I checked that using TeX Live Utility, which says that the lm package is installed. I double-checked using the command line

```
otfinfo -i `kpsewhich lmroman12-regular.otf`
```

which reports, among others, the preferred name: `Latin Modern Roman`.

This is a simple example that produces the above error message.

```
%test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
Some text ...
\end{document}

% compile command: xelatex test.tex
```

How do I set Latin Modern Roman as main font in xelatex project?

EDIT:
The motivation behind this question is that I want to set Latin Modern Math as font for Greek in polyglossia, so that I can place a few Greek words, set in upright letters, in between the English text, which should be set in Latin Modern. However, doing so results in the same error message as posted above. That's why I tried to set Lation Modern as main font in the first place. I suspect, there is a systematic problem with the lm package.

Comment: It is. And if so, the above code should work.

Comment: Not an xelatex user either, but lualatex compiles fine with your MWE. Isn't there somethnig about xetex where it only looks for fonts by name in the system font folder, not the TeXLive installation.

Comment: The posted code runs with `xelatex` for me but I've got a relatively old distribution (TeXLive 2017) so maybe some more or less recent update might have changed something.

Comment: Not sure, but try installing the font manually from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/Latin-Modern-Roman) and compile your MWE again. If it works, then there must be some path problem I guess.

Comment: On which OS? On Linux system you will have to setup fontconfig to call fonts by names.

Comment: latin modern is the default so you don't need to do anything at all

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is macOS Catalina.

Comment: is "delete the line `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}`" an answer or does you real use case have extra constraints that mean you need to re-specify the default font?